# Is the 3ds python import function available in 3.6.1?

Tags: import

I can't seem to locate the function to import a 3ds file with the new import add-on added in version 3.6 of Blender. Reference here: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.6/Add-ons

Is it possible to import a 3ds via python scripts at all? I've tried the old function `bpy.ops.import_scene.autodesk_3ds` which doesn't seem to exist. I can import through the UI after installing the add-on but I also need the python function. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a link to the addon code if it helps: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons/commit/c7a4b16aed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `bpy.ops.import_scene.autodesk_3ds` should work in Blender 3.6.2. It can be used like this:

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.autodesk_3ds(filepath='', filter_glob='*.3ds, constrain_size=0.0, use_image_search=True, use_world_matrix=False, use_keyframes=True, use_apply_transform=True)
```

The function has changed in blender 4.0, it now is `bpy.ops.import_scene.max3ds`

Here is the manual, after activation in preferences it will be located in
File ‣ Import/Export ‣ 3D Studio (.3ds)

[3ds manual entry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/import_export/scene_3ds.html)